# How to express queries in Tuple Relational Calculus?

Tags: tuple-relational-calculus

Problem:

```
Consider a relation of scheme Building(Street, Number, No.Apartments, Color, Age). 
TRC: find the oldest building in Downing Street.
```

The associated SQL statement would be:

```
SELECT MAX(Age) AS ‘Oldest building’, Street FROM Building WHERE Street = ‘Downing Street’;
```

My answer using TRC: (B stands for Building relation)

```
{V.*|V(B) | V.BAge >=Age ^ V.Bstreet = ‘Downing Street’}
```

`V.*` (it returns evry single tuple of Building)

`V(B)` (it maps variables V to Building’s tuples)

`V.BAge >=Age ^ V.Bstreet = ‘Downing Street’`(here I set the condition…maybe..)

Answer (score 1):

If this is still relevant: the hint would be to realize that the oldest building is the one such that no other building is older than it.